# Camunda process could not be started

Tags: camunda, camunda-plugin

I Used this Script in my camunda form:

```html
<form name="customerForm" role="form">

  <script cam-script type="text/form-script">

    var customerData = $scope.customerData = {
      addresses : []
    };

    $scope.addAddress = function() {
      customerData.addresses.push({});
    };


    camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {

      camForm.variableManager.createVariable({
        name: 'customerData',
        type: 'Object',
        value: customerData,
        valueInfo: {
          serializationDataFormat: 'application/json',
          objectTypeName: 'org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.example.twitter.CustomerData'
        }
      });

    });

    camForm.on('submit', function() {
      angular.forEach(customerData.addresses, function(addr) {
        delete addr.$$hashKey;
      });
    });


  </script>

  <h3>Customer Data</h3>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="firstname"
             class="form-control"
             type="text"
             required
             ng-model="customerData.firstname">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="lastname"
             class="form-control"
             type="text"
             required
             ng-model="customerData.lastname">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="vip">Is VIP Customer</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="vip"
             class="form-control"
             type="checkbox"
             ng-model="customerData.vip">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Addresses</h3>
    <a href
       ng-click="addAddress()"
       class="btn btn-default">Add</a>

    <div ng-repeat="addr in customerData.addresses">
      <hr>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street">Street</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="street"
                 class="form-control"
                 type="text"
                 required
                 ng-model="addr.street">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="zip">Zip</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="zip"
                 class="form-control"
                 type="text"
                 required
                 ng-model="addr.zipCode">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="city"
                 class="form-control"
                 type="text"
                 required
                 ng-model="addr.city">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <select id="country"
                  class="form-control"
                  required
                  ng-model="addr.country">
            <option>Germany</option>
            <option>France</option>
            <option>Italy</option>
            <option>Luxembourg</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and I got this error

> The process could not be started. :
> Cannot instantiate process definition createRating:1:1eed70bf-e4ba-11ec-afcd-764adfcc4004: Cannot find serializer for value 'ObjectValue [value=null, isDeserialized=false, serializationDataFormat=application/json, objectTypeName=org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.example.twitter.CustomerData, serializedValue=130 chars, isTransient=false]'.

how can I fix it?

Note: objectTypeName is correct I checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely reason is that the distribution you are using does not include the CAMUNDA SPIN libraries.
See:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/data-formats/
and
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/data-formats/json/

If you are using Maven, add:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-engine-plugin-spin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```